# Failed to make Dataset.filter() work in the model/official/resnet/resnet_run_loop.py file

Tags: python, tensorflow, resnet

In the official resnet model, I want to filters the dataset from test.bin by the value of 'label' when eval_only set to be True. I tried the tf.data.Dataset.filter() function to get only one class of test data but it didn't work.

```
dataset = dataset.filter(lambda inputs, label: tf.equal(label,15))
```

I put this code in the resnet_run_loop.process_record_dataset function, but it raised an error

```
 raise ValueError("`predicate` must return a scalar boolean tensor.")
```

I found that the shape of tensor 'label' is (?,) :'Tensor("arg1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32, device=/device:CPU:0)'

Comment: the inputs is the 32*32*3 data of an image, 'label' is the No. of class. 15 stands for 'bottle'. By the way, I'm using cifar100 dataset.

Comment: The function passed to filter should return a scalar as the error message indicates, but the shape of `label` is unspecified and so the shape of the output of `tf.equal()` is unspecified. If you batched the dataset before the call to `filter` then the size of `label` will indeed be larger than 1. Make sure you filter before batching, so you can safely specify the shape of `label` as `[]` (=scalar).

Comment: Also, what version of TF are you using? I've seen an issue with `filter` in 1.10.0 giving this error for legit scalars which worked fine in 1.8.0. This is probably irrelevant though.

Answer (score 0):

When comparing two tensors it is returning a `bool tensor` like this `<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=bool, numpy=array([ True,  True])>`  which is useless if you want to find an answer to the question "Is this tensor equal to another tensor?". Adding `tf.reduce_all` to it will return a tensor like this `<tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=bool, numpy=True>` and now it should work.

`dataset = dataset.filter(lambda inputs, label: tf.reduce_all(tf.equal(label,15)))`

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem in a different situation, and it turns out, as suggested in the comments, that the issue was caused by batching before filtering.

You can reproduce this using this example:

```
import pprint
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((
    tf.data.Dataset.range(0, 5),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0, 10, 15, 20, 15])
))
pprint.pprint(list(dataset.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(0, 0), (1, 10), (2, 15), (3, 20), (4, 15)]

filtered = dataset.filter(lambda x, y: y == 15)
pprint.pprint(list(filtered.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(2, 15), (4, 15)]

BATCH_SIZE = 2
batched = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
batched_filtered = batched.filter(lambda x, y: y == 15)
# ValueError: `predicate` return type must be convertible to a scalar boolean tensor. Was [...]
```

One simple solution for this problem is to [unbatch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#unbatch) your dataset, then filter, and finally batch again:

```
BATCH_SIZE = 2
batched = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
batched_filtered = batched.unbatch().filter(lambda x, y: y == 15).batch(BATCH_SIZE)
pprint.pprint(list(batched_filtered.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(array([1, 2]), array([15, 15], dtype=int32)),
#  (array([4]), array([15], dtype=int32))]
```

If you don't know or don't want to keep track of the value of `BATCH_SIZE`, you can adapt [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64610658/5811400) to calculate the batch size on demand.

I ended up combining those two solutions like this:

```
def calculate_batch_size(dataset):
    return next(iter(dataset))[0].shape[0]

def filter_batch(dataset, pred_fn):
    batch_size = calculate_batch_size(dataset)
    return dataset.unbatch().filter(pred_fn).batch(batch_size)

BATCH_SIZE = 2
batched = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)
batched_filtered = filter_batch(batched, lambda x, y: y == 15)
pprint.pprint(list(batched_filtered.as_numpy_iterator()))
# [(array([1, 2]), array([15, 15], dtype=int32)),
#  (array([4]), array([15], dtype=int32))]
```